# Setting python.venvPath has no effect

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

After setting python.venvPath to:
"python.venvPath": "/home/jfb/EVs/env/bin/python3" and restarting vs code the virtual environment does not show up in the list of Python interpreters. All the search results I have read seem to say this is all that is needed to have the virtual environment version of python show up in the list of interpreters.

Using vs code vers 1.20.1 on Mint 18.

It seems so simple so what am I missing.

Regards,  Jim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From vscode settings help:

> Path to folder with a list of Virtual Environments (e.g. ~/.pyenv,
>   ~/Envs, ~/.virtualenvs).

You should put:

"python.venvPath": "/home/jfb/EVs"

Reload vscode window and try again.

Comment: Thank you that worked. So simple. All my searches indicated the full path.

Comment: I'm completely lost. It's not gonna work if I just specify the full path to it?

Comment: The answer means that you should specify the path of the parent folder of some virtual env.